# How to create multiple urls from single

Tags: php, html

I have the following link:
http://server3.rciti.unsw.edu.au/stopandgo/index.php

Now my supervisor wants me to circulate a customised url to each of the 50 respondents he knows. He has created a list of respondents which looks something like this.

```
ID    Person name  
1     John  
2     Ram 
3     Charlie
4     Daniel

...and so on
```

He wants me to come up with the following customised urls:
http://server3.rciti.unsw.edu.au/stopandgo/index.php_1, and so on (the number after the underscore is the person id mentioned above)

This way he will be able to identify the respondent without them revealing their identity.

I am unable to find a solution to this problem. I found many sites that showed how to combine multiple urls into one, but I want the opposite.

I tried tiny url as well, but when I click the tiny url it leads me to the same original link.

Comment: *My supervisor wants me to find a solution at the earliest.* So you're basicly copying your homework here? XD  What exactly do you want to know? How to make variable URLS? Add a query string: `address/file.php?name=person1` and use `$_GET['name']` in your PHP.

Comment: Good Lord, use a database.

Answer (score 3):

Give each of them a link that looks like this:

```
http://server3.rciti.unsw.edu.au/stopandgo/index.php/?id=1
```

Then, use php to get which user has visited the site:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) //if a specific and valid user has visited the site
    $user = $_GET['id']; //will return 1, whom you know to be John

    //log John as having visited the site
    $file = 'visited.txt';                //open the file and get existing content
    $current = file_get_contents($file);  //append a new person to the end of the file
    $current .= $user."\n";         // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $current);   //write to the file
}
```

Then, give Ram the link `http://server3.rciti.unsw.edu.au/stopandgo/index.php/?id=2`

Comment: Suggestion: Add isset/is_numric?

Comment: why not a database? Text files are so much more maintenance.

Comment: Yes, you could use a database too, this way is just a little simpler (initially, and to grasp and explain) @Fred-ii-

Comment: I'd cast that as an integer though `(int) $_GET['id']` just in case ;-) `$current .= (int) $_GET['id']."\n";` Doing `&& is_numeric($_GET['user']` may not be enough.

Comment: I'm already checking for `is_numeric()` on $_GET['user'], so it won't even make it that far if it's not an integer :) @Fred-ii-

Comment: for the user array sure, but not the id.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry there's a typo there. There is only one parameter, `$_GET['id'] which is set to `$user` later on @Fred-ii-

Comment: ah...there we go Joe ;-)

Comment: I used the code shared by Joe. I thought of using database instead of file. The code is able to pick $user from the url. The echo $user shows the value 1 (say). I have a succeeding ABCD.php script where I insert this $user value with other fields collected on the previous page. However, upon adding the code I am unable to go further. The logic isn't able to proceed beyond ABCD.php. the logic works well if I don't add /?id=1 to my url. Any ideas iin case I am missing something important?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use $_GET[] variables:

   `$id = $_GET["id"];`
   `if(isset($id) && is_numeric($id)){`
   `//do something`
   `}`
2. Use HTACCESS REWRITE

   `RewriteRule /index.php_(.*) /index.php?id=$1`

Comment: I was just about to type this out XD GG